# Launch Screen storyboard clipped by "In-Call" status bar

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, launch-screen

I have a simple [**launch screen** storyboard](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-a-launch-screen-storyboard.html). It's a `UINavigationController` with a `UITableViewController` as its root. It simply shows the correct `UITitleBar` for the application.

When I launch with the larger in-call style status bar, the launch screen's title bar is clipped behind the status bar. After launch, the App correctly sizes so that the title isn't clipped – I.E. there is no problem with the *run time* storyboard.

[image: Clipped lunch screen]

Can I fix this launch clipping?

Something I notice is that the launch screen storyboard does not seem to provide top and bottom layout guides. I'm not sure is this is relevant.

Here's a screen shot of the launch screen storyboard:

[image: launch screen storyboard].

As a note, it doesn't have any vertical layout constraints to attach to, and I don't seem to be able to create any constraints using interface builders tools for this.

Comment: I have a very similar issue. My launch screen storyboard has nothing in it, I just changed the background color of the top level view. What I get on launch with the In-Call Status Bar is a colored view with a 20 pixel black bar (full width) at the very bottom of the screen.

Comment: Looks like this is mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9204917/4503700

Comment: I don't think this is the same @CharlesTruluck, as the launch screen storyboard isn't fixed size. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Are you using AutoSizing?

Comment: @CharlesTruluck I don't know – how would I check?

Comment: in other words, are you using storyboards with multiple phone sizes, constraints, etc?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the storyboard, and capture as many details of the layout constraints (if any) as possible? Thanks!

Comment: @CharlesTruluck Right – it's a single / universal size class. Ie, it's "any, any".

Comment: @gabriel_101 I've added a screen shot – good thought. It's about as simple as you can get. Just a nav controller with a table controller as its root. There are no constraints at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured out a solution.

Here's my Storyboard with constraints:

[image: Storyboard]

Basically, you don't have any constraints set for the `Table View`.
First, you should turn off freeform by going to Size Inspector -> Fixed.

Then click on your `Table View`, and press the "square with lines" constraint button and set it to this:

[image: Constraints]

I believe the reason it wasn't working was that you had freeform on without setting constraints on it- but there isn't a need for you to be using freeform.

This is what I could gather from the information you supplied, so if this doesn't fix it then you can take a look at this sample [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz_2LmLjjx4BZWhTSE1NX0dhQU0/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: The constrains you have added seem correct to me, and also necessary. They ensure that the table view is resized in accordance to it's parent view (the View Controller view).

Comment: A lot of people seem to have issues with autosizing. It came to me easily though... I find them useful.

Comment: Hi @CharlesTruluck – Thanks for your answer – I'll have an explore. I note that in the image above you have shown your _run time_ storyboard, rather than the _launch screen_ storyboard. My launch screen storyboard does not have and layout guides.

Comment: Right – Interface Builder doesn't let me add any constraints to a launch screen story board. When you say "autosizing" do you mean "auto layout" by constraints, or something to do with the size classes, by the way?

Comment: BTW – switching to fixed size scenes hasn't made it possible to add in constraints.

Comment: @CharlesTruluck – I've taken a look in the example project, thank you for your diligence in providing it. The launch screen storyboard hasn't been edited from the template projects' default though, so it's not possible to see if it is adjusted to accommodate the in call status bar or not – I suspect not.

Comment: Ah, let me fix up my answer.

Comment: @CharlesTruluck Did you have any joy with that?

Comment: Sorry, I have been trying to figure this out for a few hours now, I can link you to some resources I found but didn't find a workaround myself.

Comment: @CharlesTruluck Thanks for giving it a go! I suspect it's not possible though.

Comment: @Benjohn I find this really interesting myself. Apple is just silly. If you'd like I can file a radar with this as a feature request.

Comment: @CharlesTruluck Oh, please! Be my guest :-)